# How to integrate a RESTful webservice into SSIS

Tags: web-services, rest, ssis

I have an extremely simple RESTful webservice (i.e. www.test.com/test.xml?date1=05/252010&date2=05252010)

That returns fairly simple XML.  A client is interested in consuming this webservice via SSIS and importing it into a table.

1. Whats the best way to call a RESTful webservice with SSIS - all of the examples I have seen revolve around WSDL based webservices?
2. How do I pass parameters to the webservice (current date, etc.)?

I am just not that familiar with SSIS and am having trouble finding good documentation on interaction with RESTful webservices.

Comment: Searching over google i found [consume rest service from ssis](http://markarlenplace.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/consuming-restful-web-services-in-an-ssis-script-transformation/) may be helpful for you. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx) link also can be found helpful

Answer (score 3):

We ended up not using this feature, but based upon some more reading I found - found this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/913c63b0-2761-4f84-94e1-3c2e3af29309

In addition to some sample code which did this:

```
Dim dtYest As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now)
Dim strDate As String = dtYest.Month.ToString
strDate += "/"
strDate += dtYest.Day.ToString
strDate += "/"
strDate += dtYest.Year.ToString

Dts.Connections("HTTP Connection Manager").ConnectionString = "https://www.test.com/test.xml?begin_date="+strDate+"&end_date="+strDate
```

That's where my research ended.