# Need to call a MVC controller from SSIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssis

I need to call a mvc controller that is hosted on our server from a ssis project ( an outside application). I can call the controller from a web browser, with the following address without an extension (such as .asmx):

web server/project/controller/service

I tried to use the web service task. However, it needs a wsdl and from what I can tell, mvc controllers don't generate wsdl's. I have looked and I haven't been able to find anything that I can do to accomplish this. Has anybody done this or know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean http RESTful service more exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate a RESTful webservice into SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908445/how-to-integrate-a-restful-webservice-into-ssis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result is that I created a script task. Here is the code:

```
string url = <webservice url>;
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
```